# Where can i download AutoCad Tutorials?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, autocad

I'm pursuing Mechanical Engineering and i need to learn AUTOCAD, is there any site where i can download free video tutorials

Comment: Have you looked at youtube. Here is a link. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=autocad+tutorial. I don't think you will be able to download the videos.

Comment: Have you looked on the site of the publisher of Autocad?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to pay monthly (first month free) then there are AutoCAD tutorials on LinkedIn Learning

If you don't have to use AutoCAD then Fusion360 is a very popular and equally capable programme that engineers and designers use and its free to use for startups and hobbyists and presumably students. As its cloud based the online support and comprehensive tutorials are all available online.

Comment: In fact i would go as far as to say that a mechanical engineer should not go out and learn AutoCAD at all. But more likely Solidworks, NX, Creo, Inventor, Fusion 360 etc . All of which are free for a suitable student. It is only Civil engineering that still uses AutoCAD. For mechanical engineering AutoCAD is pretty much obsolete... Although nice to have.

Comment: @joojaa not that your point is inaccurate, but it makes civil people sound dumb and old fashioned. :( In reality, it's because civil projects tend to have so many more details that are only used once (project unique) where making standardized parts are generally a lot harder to implement than mechanical where you generally expect to make the same parts more than once. Just think of McDonalds, no two McDonalds are exactly the same, but they only use a limited selection of brands of fryers across all stores. ACad is great for drafting, so it cuts computer work hrs if all jobs are unique.

Comment: @Isa it has more to do with the way the work is spread around. Very many very small operators who collectively dont have enough clout to specify how their cad should work. Anything you can draft in autocad in an hour you can do in other cads in an hour. However the other cads have a better change management. OTOH civil engineers have a better management databases due to having skipped the better cad. I do a lot of modeling and i never do the same thing 2 times

Comment: The main difference is not how many times a thing is done. But who it is done for mechanical engineers model things to help themselves, civil engineers see it quite often as a method to satisfy code. So mechanical engineers treat their models with more respect, since the same model gives them the FEM calculation, Manufacturing paths, maintenance  plans.... Remember we do not have armies of construction workers who need to be managed, or fix/make trouble

Comment: @joojaa I would go on to add that most mechanical and electrical engineers that deal with buildings, highways, bridges, probably tend to use AutoCAD or one of its flavours a lot.  Namely because because its usually a lot of HVAC, Plumbling, Electrical Runs, etc.  A lot of information that does not need to be 3D model or need FEM work.  Furthermore, AutoCAD tends to be very popular as it has been around for a long time and has a large market share that other quite capable CAD prgs are still trying to get a significant market share.

Comment: @ForwardEd sure but then hvac lines as a example seems to commonly be under documented. I know atleast two new buildings where the hvac lines have been installed ad hoc simply because the data was mismanaged. But building engineering, and bridgebuilding is not usually considered mechanical engineering but rather civil engineering.  Though you have a point if all your doing is layout then doing 3D is probably too much. Although specifically pipe laying definitely benefits from design in 3D even if its commonly solved on spot.

Comment: @joojaa  agreed there is a benefit to it, though not a requirement.  Most engineering firms I know will try to minimize costs.  If they are a relatively small firm they will opt for plain jane AutoCAD LT.  Bigger firms that have nicer operating budgets and do bigger projects will find themselves in the world of BIM and dealing with 3D layouts.   What I was really trying to get at was it depends on the nature of mechanical engineering one is doing as to what CAD package will suit them most.  ie if you are going into aeronautical engineering look at Catia.

Comment: @ForwardEd autoCADlt lt is prohibitively expensive when compared to fusion360

Answer (score 0):

You can find many free courses if you search for it on YouTube.

Here is one example:  [AutoCad tutorials](https://thesourcecad.com/autocad-tutorials/)